# Permission.Request response always false

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have some code on the site to request additional permissions, specifically Posting to Timeline, when a user performs an action. This has been working fine until recently, where the response format from FB has changed. I've included the sample code below:

```
          FB.ui({
                method: 'permissions.request',
                'perms': 'publish_actions',
                'display': 'popup'
            }, function (response) {
                var confirm = response != null && response.perms != null && response.perms != '' && response.perms.indexOf('publish_actions') !== -1;
                $('.close').click();
            });
```

Previously, the response from this would be parsable as a string to confirm whether the user accepted the escalated permissions. However, regardless of whether the user accepts or rejects, it's just returning 'false' now.

Does anyone know if we're doing something wrong, if something has changed on FB's end, etc. Really struggling to know where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's latest changes in facebook api.
so, check out a new [doc page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) and I wish you will change the process of getting permissions to login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

[here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/), you can find a list of permissions and add to scope whatever you need, for example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
       // handle the response
     }, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'});
```

that will allow to your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.

I hope that helped somehow - let me know.

Comment: We use FB.login elsewhere in the app and that all works fine. It's specifically using the FB.UI API to do extended permission requests, are you suggesting we shouldn't be using it for this?

Comment: I think so, isn't just more correctly, useful and easier to get all permissions you need in one place when you do login? and it's suppose to work - just try it, I do not insist.